# Can you remove funds from a smart contract via API?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, external-api

There's an roi project where users deposit funds(Eth, matic etc) . According to the Dev he takes out some of these funds via API to trade with these funds. Does this sound plausible?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to interact with a smart contract is by creating a transaction, signing it, and sending it to a node to be broadcasted through the network, mined, and included into a block (unless it's a `call` and not a `send`, like when calling a `view` or `pure` function from a smart contract), directly or indirectly.

You could use an API, let's say, a backend in a regular language that has a private key to sign transactions and send them to the blockchain. Or you sign a transaction and send it to a backend that will send it to the blockchain to be broadcasted.

Maybe the Dev is talking about the node API to communicate with it and send transactions directly?

Directly or indirectly, the result is the same: create a transaction, sign it, and send it to a node to be broadcasted and mined.